# Access 2016 two table join based on a field found in another table

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

In advance, thank you for your assistance and explanation, I am a novice at best and trying to teach myself.

I have two different types of claims tables, [claim_a] and [claim_b]. Each of these tables capture similar data and have one claim record per row. I have a similar form to display data by record for each table. One of my forms has a grid that captures documents sent and the date sent.

In a third table, [documents], each instance of a document sent is associated with an ssn, claim_num, first, last and clm_type, doc_type and date_sent.

I want to create one query that would output all correspondence sent for both claim tables. I realize I could just do two individual queries but I think this can be done and is not too difficult, I am just missing something and would like to know what. I have tried various join type (inner, left, right) and get various results but nothing that is actually correct. With INNER JOIN, I only got 78 records but am expecting 2,261 and when I did LEFT OUTER, I got 3,070 which totals more than what I had in my [documents] table-I do understand that an outer join with one row in the LEFT table that matches two rows in the RIGHT table will return as two ROWS. 
I have also been sure to use parenthesis in my first join statement which based on Google searches seems to be related to Access. I also tried using where clauses too.

I think the problem may be that some of the records in [documents] do not correspond to a record in either claims table. I also just tried joining one claim table to [documents] but even that did not return the expected number of results.

Here are few of the joins I have tried:

1. Inner Join for one table: My output was missing 4 records for an SSN with 6 total records and I could not figure out why it skipped over the remaining 4. It was only for this SSN. I had other SSNs with more than 6 records.

   ```
   SELECT documents.date, documents.doc_type, 
   FROM documents INNER JOIN claim_a ON documents.ssn = 
   claim_a.ssn WHERE (((documents.clm_type)="Life Only")) OR 
   (((documents.clm_type)<>("Health")) AND (("Life/ ADB")<>False) AND 
   (("Life")<>False));
   ```
2. I got 78 records with this join

   ```
   SELECT documents.date, documents.doc_type, 
   FROM (documents INNER JOIN claim_a ON documents.ssn = 
   claim_a.ssn) INNER JOIN claim_b ON documents.ssn = 
   claim_b.ssn;
   ```
3. I got 3070 records with this join

   ```
   SELECT documents.date, documents.doc_type, 
   FROM (documents LEFT OUTER JOIN claim_a ON documents.ssn = 
   claim_a.ssn) LEFT OUTER JOIN claim_b ON documents.ssn = 
   claim_b.ssn;
   ```
4. I got the correct number of results with this query but I am concerned it will not work with my Master Form to display header specific information for my form associated with table, claim_b.

   ```
   SELECT documents.date, documents.doc_type, 
   FROM documents LEFT JOIN claim_a ON documents.ssn = 
   claim_a.ssn WHERE (((documents.clm_type)<>""));
   ```

I am obviously doing something wrong. Can someone please advise?

Comment: Query 4 actually worked for both of my tables in the form view. I made sure to use SSN as my master/child link when creating my forms. 
@Don George...originally I was not going to do a UNION query with the two separate queries but using a UNION is a much better idea, thank you.

Comment: if my answer worked, can you please accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a Union query between the two claims tables to get a list of all claims.  Then use the results of theat query to get the document list.

Union query

```
Select ssn from claim_a
Union all select ssn from claim_b
```

Save this with a name like SSN_List, then join it to Documents in another query

```
Select * from Documents
left join SSN_List on Documents.ssn=SSN_List.ssn
```

And of course change the 2nd query as needed to get the information you need from Documents.

This can probably be done in one query, but I find it easier to understand and use the 2 step approach.